# The eigenvectors obtained in the diagonalization in the paper "Two Soluble Models of an Antiferromagnetic Chain" by Lieb, Schultz and Mattis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematics, eigenvalue

The diagonalization involves few transformations, that transforms the anisotropic XY model in a matrix eigenvalue equation as $(A-B)(A+B)\phi_k= \lambda^2_k \phi_k$ where the matrix $(A-B)(A+B)$ has a form $\frac{1-\gamma^2}{4}(\delta_{i+1,j-1}+ \delta_{i-1,j+1})+\frac{1+\gamma^2}{2}\delta_{i,j}$. The solution using translational invariance is given as $\phi_{k,j}=\sqrt{2/N}\sin(kj)$ for $k>0$ and $\phi_{k,j}=\sqrt{2/N}\cos(kj)$ for $k<0$, as written in Equation (2.18a) of the paper.
I am able to obtain the equation but not able to obtain the eigenvectors.

Link to the article https://doi.org/10.1016/0003-4916(61)90115-4